# Stacking divs into a pyramid using jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm attempting to use jquery to stack elements into a pyramid, but I can't see to get it right.

For example, i would like to have a list with 3 items (apple, banana, cheeto). Using droppable or sortable, i would like to move those items to a different element, and stack them in a pyramid.

[.........][cheeto][............]

[apple][...........][banana]

So far, I've been able to combine the list element and the empty element so they are all a sortable, and i can take the list items and drop them into the pyramid element. This works.

The problem is preventing the ability to stack the items in a configuration other than a pyramid,  for example, inserting apple, banana and cheeto into the top row.

I would also like to have the elements that are moved to actually be moved in the DOM. I think this means that the draggable/droppable function won't work for this application, but i might be wrong about that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Quite a complex problem, this. If I went at it from scratch, I would probably use a combination of bootstrap and jQueryUI to create the pyramid using bootstrap's Grid System: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem and then define which of them are droppable to form the visual pyramid. Not really an answer, but I'm interested in your eventual approach to this. Please update!

Comment: You need to provide some code or more preferably a jsfiddle. It will be easier to help you. Do you mean a pyramid with one item on top, then 2, then 3, then 4 etc? Or do you mean the items create an empty triangle 1, then 2,then 2,then 2,then 2,then however many it takes to bridge the bottom? We need some clarity.

Comment: is this code architecture or visual representation?  you mention JQUI so I assume the latter...I don't get what would be so difficult?  assuming, once again, that you are ok with each element being a specific width/height...lets say a rectangle.  create an empty class for filler space and add your real elements programmatically (or by hand I guess).  whats the actual problem, or rather, end result?  try to explain it a bit better if you could please

Answer (score 1):

I've made simple fiddle for your issue http://jsfiddle.net/QXwyk/6/ 
Base concept was to change ul list to pytamid by css. While adding elements work pretty well, unfortunatelly it got messed up while moving elements in pyramid. Maybe this will help you a bit or it might be a good place for further testing.

Html

```
<ul id="pyramid" class="pyramid sortable">
</ul>

<ul id="fruits" class="fruits sortable">
    <li>cheeto</li>
    <li>apple</li>
    <li>banana</li>
    <li>kiwi</li>
    <li>strawberry</li>
    <li>limon</li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
$("#fruits, #pyramid").sortable({
    connectWith: ".sortable",
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
    cursor: "move",
}).disableSelection();
```